# How to remove the indentation in enumerate paragraphs but keep the indentation in the first line of a new paragraph?

Tags: formatting, enumerate, indentation

I want to remove the indentation in enumerate paragraphs but still keep the indentation in the first line of a new paragraph. I tried to use `[wide = 0pt]` with `enumitem` package. However, new paragraphs in enumerate are not indented (see blue arrows in the picture).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries \Roman*.}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue. In ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. 

Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices.

\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt]
\item Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Diam sit amet nisl suscipit.

Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis.

Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam.

\item Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida.

Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, listparindent=15pt]` result in the expected output?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the paraghraph indentation inside of your `enumerate` environment, add `listparindent=\parindent` to its options:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries \Roman*.}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue. In ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. 

Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices.

\begin{enumerate}[wide = 0pt, listparindent=\parindent]
\item Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Diam sit amet nisl suscipit.

Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis.

Nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam.

\item Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida.

Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```